# How do you get the elixir compiler to show warnings when running a phoenix server?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix, elixir-iex

Running a phoenix server in iex session via mix, like:

```
iex -S mix phx.server
```

Will sometimes give a list of warnings like:

```
Compiling 1 file (.ex)
warning: variable "user" is unused
  lib/app_web/controllers/user_controller.ex:37
```

But seemingly only the first time the server is run, after which I suppose its cached and so it doesn't show up. How can I at a later time see these warnings to fix them? Thanks.

Comment: Just a note: if you change something on a configuration file (`config/*.exs`), it is necessary to run again the server again (`iex -S mix phx.server` or `mix phx.server`) and compile everything again, so it will show you the warnings again.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Run `mix compile --force` to see all warnings again.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method, use `mix clean` before `iex -S mix phx.server`, which will clean cache and show up warnings again.

Comment: I recommend to everyone interested in `mix clean` to read [its documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/1.12/Mix.Tasks.Clean.html) before to use it: "deletes all build artifacts for the current project".